# How to use pry-byebug in an example script for a gem?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, pry

I'm working on making my first gem, which is not a Rails app, is a tic-tac-toe library with some AI in it, so I can play a computer opponent that will never lose and force a win if possible.

Right now I am trying to debug the attack strategy in the AI, but I can't seem to figure out how to get pry-byebug working in my test script, specfically, have the debugging commands like `step`, `next`, etc. work upon hitting a `binding.pry`.

The gem, named smart-tac-toe, has the following directory structure:

```
$ ls smart-tac-toe
example  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  Guardfile  lib  LICENSE.txt  Rakefile  README.md  smart_tac_toe.gemspec  spec  tmp
```

As you can see above, there is an 'example' directory in my gem which contains "example.rb", where I use the classes I've made.

However, when I use `binding.pry` and try to use `step` and `next`, the Pry session just exits  and the script keeps running.

In my smart_tac_toe.gemspec file, I clearly have pry-byebug:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "pry-byebug", '~>2.0.0'
```

and at the top of my example.rb file, I have tried requiring the proper gems:

```
require 'pry'
require 'pry-byebug'
require "../lib/smart_tac_toe.rb"
```

I am using Ruby 2.1.1p76 , the repo for this gem is located at https://github.com/discotroll65/smart_tac_toe

Also, though putting binding.pry into my example script does throw me into a debugging session, initially it is in a reading mode, and I have to press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit that before I can start doing repl stuff. Any thoughts as to why this may be?

Comment: What happens if you use `byebug` instead of `binding.pry`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, looking into this more I realized (I think...still kind of new to the game) a couple things --

1.) If you want to if have

```
require 'pry'
```

at the top of your ruby file and have it work in general, it would help to install it in your development environment using your terminal:

```
user@machine/currentdirectory/$ gem install pry
```

likewise with pry-byebug:

```
user@machine/currentdirectory/$ gem install pry-byebug
```

2.) The real answer to my initial question is to use

```
byebug
```

in my script as the debugging hook, instead of

```
binding.pry
```

(thanks @mtm for the suggestion!)

when I do use byebug though, while `step` and `next` work properly, the REPL it throws me into doesn't have any color, and isn't as nice in general...anyway to fix that?

Comment: `byebug` instead of `binding.pry` does it for me! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overdoing it. This works for me:

```
require 'pry-byebug'

puts 'foo'
binding.pry
puts 'bar'
```