# Debug rubymine 8.0 and ruby 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine, ruby-debug-ide

I'm trying to debug my rails application on rubymine 8.0.1 and but when I put a breakpoint it's interrupted with exit code -1.

I use a remote server with vagrant I set in rubymine debug config the host and the port that I use.

My workspace

- ruby 2.2.1
- rails 4.2
- rubymine 8.0.1
- vagrant

Gem file

```
actionmailer (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
actionpack (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
actionview (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
activejob (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
activemodel (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
activerecord (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
activesupport (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
arel (6.0.3)
aws-sdk (2.2.1)
aws-sdk-core (2.2.1)
aws-sdk-resources (2.2.1)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.8.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capistrano (3.4.0)
capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
capistrano-rails (1.1.5)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
colorize (0.7.7)
debase (0.2.1)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.8.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.3.2)
jmespath (1.1.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.7 x86_64-linux)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.99, 2.6.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.3, 5.4.3)
mock_redis (0.15.4)
multi_json (1.11.2)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (3.0.1)
nokogiri (1.6.6.4)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-cors (0.4.0)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.5, 4.2.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
redis (2.1.1)
ref (2.0.0)
responders (2.1.0)
ruby-debug-ide (0.6.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.4.4)
sprockets (3.4.1, 3.4.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
sshkit (1.7.1)
test-unit (3.0.8)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Error shows.

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:45202
^C/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `wait'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `block in prepare_debugger'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in `prepare_debugger'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:85:in `debug_program'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what is going on but if you can't get it working after a while, I would recommend [pry](http://pryrepl.org)

Comment: Can I use pry with rubymine and the graphic debug mode? I used byebug after of ruby-debug-ide

Comment: This might answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573040/2750819